# ModX Manager Failing to Load

Tags: php, apache, modx, modx-revolution

I am attempting to login to my ModX install.

The manager login screen comes up, and I can type in my username and password.  Once I hit login I am presented with the `The connection was reset` in firefox, and in Chrome with `No data received` - `Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

The server is Ubuntu 13.10 running Apache 2 with php 5.5.3 and is my own personal server.  All I've done is keep up with updates...

What can the issue be?

I don't know if this will help, but here is the log from my last restart of apache:

```
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:19.928031 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9826] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.049656 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 11164] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.077715 2014] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 11165] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.079094 2014] [:notice] [pid 11168] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 11168)
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.129505 2014] [:notice] [pid 11165] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.129536 2014] [:notice] [pid 11165] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp 
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.232375 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11165] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.3     mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.5+ OpenSSL/1.0.1e configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 10 13:07:21.232458 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 10 13:08:09.296802 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00051: child pid 11173 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 10 13:08:09.296887 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00051: child pid 11187 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 10 13:08:34.337400 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00051: child pid 11212 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 10 13:08:35.338551 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00051: child pid 11188 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Thu Apr 10 13:08:35.338631 2014] [core:notice] [pid 11165] AH00051: child pid 11213 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Comment: You have a coredump which means Apache itself crashed. So first thing is to fix that. How are you running php? you're using prefork, but it looks like you're using mod_fcgid too. Are you using php-fpm? or are you using the DSO module to load php?

Comment: how would I check?   its a ubuntu 13.10 server

Comment: did you recently upgrade from apache 2.2 to 2.4? that would cause this trouble. run httpd -V and post it in your question. Also httpd -M shows which modules are loaded.

Comment: i get `No command 'httpd' found`... Hoever, it is Apache 2.4.6.   fcgid is enabled. along with fastcgi.  I cannot tell if fpm... would I be able to get that from apache2.conf?

Comment: I'd suggest reinstalling Apache2 and all modules. The issue is not Modx. I don't think it's PHP either.

Comment: I don't think it is either.  However, every other site I have on this server runs fine... which still has me believing it's ModX.  I have a Joomla site, a Wordpress site, and a bunch of CakePHP, and CodeIgniter apps as sites setup, and all work perfectly fine...

Comment: @OptimusCrime [reinstalling?!](http://youtu.be/nn2FB1P_Mn8?t=10s).. o7th, are you really using `mod_fcgi` and `mod_python`? If not, you're bloating your apache workers.

Comment: Yeah.... tried reinstalling... bloating my what ? ;)

Comment: ok.  I disabled mod_python, the issue still occurs